# flask: session life time

Tags: security, http, flask

In my web app, I'm using token based login - for most of the pages. For the rest of the pages, it's session based. So I have a common constants that keeps the two values in sync so that all the pages behaves correctly.

For session: I use the following code:

```
 app.permanent_session_lifetime = timedelta(seconds=DEFAULT_TOKEN_TIMEOUT)
```

It's been working fine until I decided to increase the value to 5 days. What happens then is that the token is still valid and all the API calls are fine. But those pages that rely on a session stops working after a while. So it looks like the above code doesn't work - or there is a ceiling to this value.

I plan to move all pages to use token and API but for now: is there a ceiling value to the session life time? Can it be increased? Is it a good idea to keep such a long permanent session?

Answer (score 0):

Default timedelta in the flask is 31 days. I have set up sessions for 50 days and everything is ok.
My setting configuration code

```
permanent_session_lifetime = timedelta(days=50)
```

The problem may be the second for such a long time. Try using options days

```
 app.permanent_session_lifetime = timedelta(days=DEFAULT_TOKEN_TIMEOUT)
```

Answer (score 0):

This also works. I'm using it in my beta version project. No problem yet.

```
permanent_session_lifetime = timedelta(seconds=432000)
```